# Github workflow executing unexpextedly

Tags: github, workflow

Ok, so I'm trying to get a workflow to execute on a specific branch, with a specific tag.

So I wrote this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'branchname'
    tags:
      - 'tagname'
```

with the expectation that it would run whenever something on the `branchname` branch was taged with `tagname`. Instead it seems like it is being run on master whenever something is pushed, regardless of tags. Can someone explain why?